Letters and numbers that share something in common
Why are these two "equations" true?

L + I = 900
7 + 1 = 405

Note: They're not all super accurate, but accurate enough once you realize the method I used to make this little puzzle. No knowledge other than trivial is needed.

It's about

 clock,  put the letters or numbers into clock layout:


 


 3:00 + 6:00 = 9:00

 ~8:35 + 7:30 = 16:05 = 4:05 p.m.


This is it, well done!

Dude... I don't consider myself a genius but I'm not dumb. And this one, you figured it out that easily. I mean, dude...

I don't know if the same rule is applied to each, but for the second one I see

 405 = 45 + 360.
 Pictorially 7 is (not exactly) 45°, and then 1 is a circle: 360°.

